# HttpContext namespace

Tags: nunit, httpcontext

I need to write a NUnit script to test the cache data. I added a project(Class libray) in my project and add reference to NUnit.Framework. But i am not getting the "HttpContext" in my code. Please tell me which namespace i should include to get this. I am doing with the help of the post

[Unit test HttpContext.Current.Cache or other server-side methods in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489819/unit-test-httpcontext-current-cache-or-other-server-side-methods-in-c)

Please help

Thanks San

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpContext is a class in NameSpace System.Web

Comment: I already have that namespace... but then also i am not getting.. can you please tell me what will be the problem.

Comment: Do you add System.Web as reference? 

Click Menu: Project->Add Reference -> choose .Net tab then select System.Web -> OK