# Nunit script to test cache data

Tags: c#, testing, caching, nunit

I am trying write a sample NUnit test script to check the value in cache

I wrote the code like

```
 [TestFixture]

class Authorization
{
    class AutherizationEntity
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }          
        public int OperationCode { get; set; }
        public bool permission { get; set; }
    }


    [SetUp]
    public void Initialize()
    {

            //if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["UserRights"] == null) 
            //{
                List<AutherizationEntity> AuthorisationObject = new List<AutherizationEntity>();

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    AutherizationEntity AEntity = new AutherizationEntity();
                    AEntity.OperationCode = 10;
                    AEntity.permission = true;
                    AEntity.UserID = i;
                    AuthorisationObject.Add(AEntity);
                }
                HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("UserRights", AuthorisationObject);  //Here i am getting the exception in NUnit
            //}

    }

    [TestCase]
    public void AuthorizeUser()
    {           
        int UserId = 1;
        int OperationCode = 10;        
        Boolean HaveRight = false;

        List<AutherizationEntity> AuthEntity = new List<AutherizationEntity>();
        AuthEntity = (List<AutherizationEntity>)HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("UserRights");

        foreach (AutherizationEntity Auth in AuthEntity)
        {
            if ((Auth.UserID == UserId) && (Auth.OperationCode==OperationCode))
            {
                HaveRight = Auth.permission;
            }
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(HaveRight, true);
    }     

}
```

But when i am trying to run the script with NUnit i am getting an exception

Authorization.AuthorizeUser():
SetUp : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

NUnit doesn't run on a web context so `HttpContext.Current` is null. You'll need to create a we context manually if you want to test that.

You could create a mock class for your httpcontext. Please Google `mock httpcontext` and you'll find several links that may be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. It might be helpful if you could give me little more explanation or a helpful link

Comment: @san: I don't have a specific sample to show. I suggested on my post a google search that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

When testing code bound towards the HttpContext you have to rely upon abstractions and use a fake/stubbed http context. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489819/unit-test-httpcontext-current-cache-or-other-server-side-methods-in-c) for more information on the topic.

Unfortunately the cache object (and the Cache class) is not possible to fake easily, since it's a sealed class. The way to go is to create a wrapper class with a corresponding interface around the Cache object and fake/stub/mock that in your test.

You can access the Cache class outside a web application, but in this case you'd probably not want to do that. Accessing the cache can be done by referencing the System.Web assembly and using the HttpRuntime class.

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Caching;
…
Cache cache = HttpRuntime.Cache;
```